# CORS filter gives 403 in POST only in Chrome

Tags: tomcat, cors, http-status-code-403

I have following configuration in Tomcat. I get 403 error when making POST requests from my local machine browser to remote server.
I use EASYUI JQuery components, and they work fine on IE10+ and Firefox! Only chrome is complaining this. Can any one hep?

```
  <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem when sending a JSON object via POST, and solved by explicitly setting a JSON content type header:

```
var config = { headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

$http.post(url, config)
.success
...
```

It seems Chrome is unable to automatically detect the Content Type as well as Firefox etc. can.